# Does it ever make sense to write the Cosmological Constant as: $\Lambda_{\mu\nu}$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, cosmological-constant

In Einstein's Field Equations, does it ever make sense to write the Cosmological Constant as: $\Lambda_{\mu\nu}$? It was written this way in a BBC Horizon Programme on Sunday,

[image: Einstein's Field Equations - Screenshot from BBC2 Horizon programme]

But, $\Lambda$ is a constant, so how can it have subscripts? I think they meant to put in a lowercase $g$ (to represent the Metric Tensor) (i.e. $\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$), or is there some sense in the way they showed it? This is not a duplicate, I'm asking about notation not about whether it is a scalar or not.

Comment: Check out the answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159059/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the cosmological constant a scalar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159059/)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the equation in question?

Comment: They probably are just defining $\Lambda_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} \Lambda$, which is kind of weird but not invalid.

Comment: As for why, there's no deep reason, it's just that the equation probably wasn't written by an actual physicist.

Comment: It's a scalar, but my question was whether there is any legitimate use of the notation they used in the BBC2 Horizon programme (shown in the screenshot). I gather that there is not, (unless anyone can think of it still...?) - so they made a mistake. Surprised they didn't check more carefully on a quality programme?  It was, - after all, - the sole point of the programme.

Comment: Never seen it notated like that anywhere else (and I actually didn't notice this when I watched it!). Pretty sure it's just a mistake, or else deliberately fudged to avoid having to write down and thus explain the metric tensor.

Comment: the minus sign is also wrong btw